# Custom filter for full text search. IFilter implementation

Tags: sql-server, com, full-text-search, ifilter

I have my extension file named .sc that looks like xml whre one tag contains byte code of .doc file. I need search words in this .doc file. So need to create my own custom filter for SQL Server full text search. I found out that SQL Server and Windows Desktop Search use the same filters. I tried to run filter from [this](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/winui/WindowsSearch/IFilterSample) example on Windows 10, but it use an embeded Pdf filter. Where I can get worked filter example sources for Windows 10 that will work like RarFilter dll from [here](http://www.ifiltershop.com/rar-ifilter.html)?  Or how can I create own filter for my created .sc extension?

Comment: Can you please translate that message in Cyrillic into English?

Comment: @marc_s The string binding is invalid

Comment: I deleted the error, because I solved problem and found out that FilterSample desigion does not fit